# IIS Express maximum port number on Windows 10

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, port, iis-express

Is there a maximum port number for IIS Express on Windows 10?

When I try to run it on ports higher than 62546 on Windows 10 I get the error below:

```
Failed to register URL "http://localhost:62556/" for site "Development Web Site" application "/". Error description: Acess denied. (0x80070005)
```

Tried both on IIS Express 8 and 10, with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce it. With a tool such as [Jexus Manager](http://jexusmanager.com)  it would be quite easy to test it out.

Maybe some other software takes the port range on your computer, and you should use `netstat -aon` command to check that out,

https://blog.lextudio.com/2012/10/port-already-in-use-then-who-uses-it/

Comment: Great tips on netstat and Jexus.  
However, I tried both and none worked.  
Jexus says site starting but when I refresh it's stopped.  
netstat accuses no port listening on this port.